# Why do some PL choose to have a dedicated keyword for elseif instead of like in C?

Tags: syntax, language-comparison

In C, `else if` is nothing but a new `if` statement after a single-statement `else` clause. Why do languages like Python and Ruby have a dedicated construct for `elsif`/`elif`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

They do this to avoid the **dangling else problem**.

In many programming languages, the syntax for else-if statements is ambiguous. For example, consider the following C program:

```
if(a) if (b) x++; else y++;
```

Which `if` should the else belong to? Is it the inner one?

```
if (a)
    if (b)
        x++;
    else
        y++;
```

or the outer one?

```
if (a)
    if (b)
        x++;
else
    y++;
```

This ambiguity is known as the "dangling else problem". One way that programming languages can avoid it is to require delimiters around the "then" and the "else" part of the `if`. Some languages, such as Swift, mandate that there must be curly braces:

```
if (a) {
   x++;
} else {
   y++;
}
```

Some languages instead use `then` and `end` keywords, for a similar effect. For example, Lua:

```
if a then
   x = x + 1
else
   y = y + 1
end
```

However, if our language requires these delimiters around the `else` then we cannot write `else if` as we do in C. Because `else` must be followed by an open curly brace, we would end up with open braces between the `else` and the `if`, and a long sequence of closing delimiters at the end.

```
if (a) {
    x++;
} else { if (b) {
    y++;
} else { if (c) {
    z++;
} else {
    w++;
}}} /*ouch!*/
```

Having an `elseif` keyword is an elegant way to avoid this `}}}` avalanche. We can still mandate braces after `if` and `else`, but there aren't those pesky braces between the two

Swift and Rust avoid the `else { if` problem by special casing the `else if`. Their grammar says that the next token after the `else` must be a `{`, unless it's an `if`. This is certainly a valid way to solve the problem and avoids creating a new keyword. That said, the programmer must be aware that `else if` is a special case. If one is used to languages with traditional if-else syntax, they might expect they are allowed to write to substitute any other statement in place of the `if` statement in the `else if`. In languages with `elseif` this question doesn't come up because it's loud and clear that `elseif` is special.

Comment: PHP is a clike just like C and JS, and it has `elseif`. I wonder what the reason is there, maybe to save the keystroke.

Comment: The dangling `else` problem doesn't contain any occurrences of `else if`, and would still occur in C's grammar if `elseif` were to be written instead. The point about block delimiters is reasonable, but I think it would be clearer if this answer said that it's a consequence of requiring delimiters around `if` and `else` blocks, which is done in part to avoid the dangling `else` problem but also for other reasons (hence such languages also tend to require block delimiters for loops, try/catch, and so on).

Comment: Also technically the dangling `else` problem could also be solved by only requiring braces around the `if` body, and not necessarily also the `else` body, which would allow `else if` to still be written. Though this might seem inconsistent to users of the language.

Comment: This may explain some languages, but Python uses `elif` and it does not suffer from the dangling else problem.

Comment: In Python, the dangling else problem is avoided by significant indentation, which is analogous to mandating braces around the if/else body. Python's elif allows if-else-if without having to nest the elses in increasingly deeper levels of indentation (which would be analogous to the `}}}` problem discussed in my answer).

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand, but why is the dangling else problem a problem? Doesn't C unambiguously specify that it's the first of the options you gave since an else corresponds to its nearest if?

Comment: The C specification does specify the nearest-if rule, so that all compilers will do the same thing with unbraced if-else. However, the real problem is that it's more confusing for programmers. The programmer might be thinking of the second option, but the compiler will actually do the first one.

Comment: More specifically, the programmer is likely to *write* the second version, and their use of indentation may think it will work as they expect, but it will actually be parsed as the first version. This is similar to what happens when they write a braceless `if` or `else` and later add a second statement without adding braces.

Answer (score 22):

The way the chaining of `else if` blocks is defined in C follows naturally from the way the grammar allows for braceless blocks:

```
if (x) {
} else if (y) {
}
```

being parsed the same as

```
if (x) {
} else
    if (y) {
    }
```

i.e.

```
if (x) {
} else {
    if (y) {
    }
}
```

When you allow for such constructs in the syntax, a dedicated keyword is useless.

On the other hand, if you take Python, for example, since blocks are defined by indentation (and not by enclosing tokens such as braces), this is not valid out-of-the-box (you have to special-case it, whereas in C it was "free"):

```
if x:
    pass
else if y:
    pass
```

So, given that we're forced to create that special case, it makes sense to choose something shorter than `else if`, hence `elif` (or `elsif`).

Answer (score 16):

Another reason for `elseif/elsif/elif` is if the conditional construct has a keyword terminator, like the shell's `fi` or Lua's `end`.  You don't want to be writing `else if` because now you're writing nested `if`'s, which have to be terminated with a whole sequence of repeated `end` tokens.

Comment: That is the reason I added `ElseIf` to AEC (my programming language).

Answer (score 13):

## They need one

In C-style languages like JS, you can put a single statement after an `if` to run just that one:

```
if (x == 1) print("x is 1!");
```

In fact, `else if` isn't even necessarily interpreted specially by the compiler. It could just be parsed as an `if` statement directly following the `else`.

However, in languages like Python where you can't do this, it would be natural to have a keyword specifically for else-if since you don't get that for free.

Comment: There are languages that have "else if" as separate words but do not allow a single expression after `if` (like Rust)

Comment: @mousetail That's true, I was going to touch on how it's possible to detect an `else if` even without that, might come back and do that in a sec

Answer (score 4):

`else if` could never be an invalid construct in any reasonable language.

Languages that also use `elseif` tend to have enforced grouping constructs. That is, you cannot omit the braces or equivalents after the `if` conditions. In many cases it's because the language is using specific grouping constructs for every control structure, that is, `if`...`endif`, `for`...`endfor`. In other cases it's because grouping is an important part of the grammar, for example in Python and Tcl.

In these cases, if you don't use `elseif`, a long conditional statement would become:

```
if(...)
    ...;
else
    if(...)
        ...;
    else
        if(...)
            ...;
        else
            ...;
        endif;
    endif;
endif;
```

which stacks many `endif`s at the end and is not very practical.

There are languages like PHP, where grouping constructs are not enforced, but also have `elseif`. Many people choose to use `else if` anyway, and some may not even realize `elseif` existed. So your design decisions may not matter that much, after all.

There are also languages like the LISP variants. Everybody already knows that code in them would always have this problem everywhere, so nobody cares about the little more problems caused by not having `elseif` with enforced grouping constructs.

Answer (score 0):

`elseif`/`elsif`/`elif` is shorter, which is important in [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com).

Comment: There are much terser ways to write `if`-`else`-chains than by adding the `elif` keyword. Even in C you'd write something like `a?b:c?d:e?…`.